# Debugging parse error

Tags: java, xml, xpath, workflow

I am getting a parse error at line 1 column 29.

```
if (xpath:{Path for file location}.equals("xname")) {
    workflow.setVariable("variable);
    workflow.setVariable("variable);
        ([column1]
        ,[column2]
        ,[column2])   
 VALUES
         (xpath:{}
        ,'xpath:{}'
        ,'xpath:{}'
         ) );
 }
```

What do I need to do to fix this?

Comment: If you need help. Then the least you can do it make the question readable.

Answer (score 0):

If I had to guess, I'd say it's due to the misspelled "locaiton" in your path.

Answer (score 0):

If this is Java code, there are several things wrong with it:

- The `xpath:{/workflow/variables/locaiton}` construct is something that doesn't exist in Java. It's invalid syntax. See [this tutorial](http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2005/01/12/xpath.html)  for more information.
- The SQL Statement should be put inside double quotes